# "malloc in local function, free memory in main" is it ok? How?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, free

I learned in book that if I need to return a pointer from a function, I use `malloc()` and get memory from the heap. I was wondering how I can `free()` up the memory allocated after the function.

Is OK to do what I did in the following code to free that memory? If it's not correct, what's correct way to free memory after function?

```
int *Add_them_up (int *x, int *y)
{
    int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof (int));
    *p = *x + *y;
    return p;
}


int main ()
{   
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;
    int *presult = NULL;
    presult = Add_them_up (&c, &d);
    printf ("the result of adding is:%d\n", *presult);
    free (presult);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: @shinhwa there is a serious issue you are missing here.

Comment: @SouravGhosh You have ignored a serious issue my friend.

Comment: @Sumeet Kindly enlighten me.

Comment: @SouravGhosh See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, your code is correct.<sup>condition apply, see note below</sup>

To [`free()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free) the allocated memory, you only need to pass the returned pointer from `malloc()` and family.

As you're getting the same pointer returned by `malloc()` back from the `Add_them_up()` function and storing the same in `presult`, in the `main()` function you can call

```
free (presult);
```

without any issues. It will carry out the intended job.

---

Note: You're missing two aspects here, e.g.

1. Please [see why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in C.
2. Always check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.

That said, just a suggestion, always try to use the form

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

which makes the allocation statement independent of the type of `p`, resulting in a most robust code.

Comment: thanks for your comments and explanation. I realized the 2nd aspect, I'm learning the first one.

Comment: The code is correct as far as syntax and functionality go, but it is bad program design.

Answer (score 4):

This is generally considered poor program design. The module that does the malloc() should be designed so that it is also responsible for doing the free().

You should never design programs so that some external routine is supposed to clean up the mess from your module. It is all common sense really.

So in this case, you should add a wrapper function around free(), which main() can call. main() shouldn't need to know or care about how your routines perform dynamic allocation/deallocation.

Note that programs that don't follow this program design tend to have memory leak-related bugs.

Comment: Well said, also I think there has been one issue left out.

Comment: @Sumeet Dangling pointers is only an issue if the routines are expected to be called yet again with the same inputs. In that case, it is up to the routines which do the malloc/free to handle it.

Comment: But still making it NULL is a good thing to do, don't you think.

Comment: @Sumeet It entirely depends on the nature and functionality of the code. It might be very good and necessary, or it might be superfluous clutter.